# GitHubのオープンソースプロジェクトがビルドできません

Tags: swift, xcode, realm

RealmSwiftを使ってToDoみたいなものを作ろうとしているのですが、ちょうど良いサンプルが見つかったのでさっそくダウンロードしてビルドしてみました。

https://github.com/hossamghareeb/realmtasks

しかし、そのままビルドすると以下のようなエラーが出て止まってしまいます
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
どのようにしたらビルドできるようになるでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ずいぶん古いプロジェクトなので最新版のXcode 7.3ではそのままではコンパイルできません。
Swiftの仕様が変わっているためです。

ビルドする方法は2つあります。
まず古いXcodeを使う方法です。
こちら https://developer.apple.com/downloads/ から過去のバージョンのXcodeがダウンロードできますので、7.0.1をダウンロードしてください。
7.0.1でしたらそのままビルドして実行できます。

もう一つは最新版のXcodeでもビルドできるようにコードを修正することです。
サンプルコードとして参考にするということなので、最終的にはこちらの方法がいいでしょう。

まずは、`pod update`を実行して、依存ライブラリを最新にアップデートします。
（依存ライブラリが古くてビルドエラーが起きているため）
これでRealmのバージョンが0.95から0.102になります。

そして、Swift 2で変更になったエラー処理のコードなどをSwift 2でビルドできるように修正します。
このプロジェクトの場合は`Realm.write()`メソッドの部分に`try!`を付けるだけでビルドできるようになります。

Comment: kishikawa katsumiさん
毎度ありがとうございます！

なるほど一筋縄では行かなそうですね........。
状況を鑑みてやってみようと思います！